# Will socket.io use middleware that express uses

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

If I use `express` middleware will `socket.io` use it too?

I need the middleware called for every http request and `socket.io` request

```js
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { /* options */ });

// If I use express middleware will socket.io use it too?
app.use(middleware)

// Or I should use it for io too
io.engine.use(middleware);

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Socket.IO documentation about [compatibility with Express middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#compatibility-with-express-middleware):

> Since they are not bound to a usual HTTP request/response cycle,
> Socket.IO middlewares are not really compatible with Express
> middlewares.
>
> That being said, starting with version `4.6.0`, [Express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) are
> now supported by the underlying engine:
>
> ```
> io.engine.use((req, res, next) => {
>   // do something
>   next();
> });
> ```
>
> The middlewares will be called for each incoming HTTP requests,
> including upgrade requests.

**Edit:**

Maybe you can just implement a brief example and give it a try. Something simple like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Express Middleware");
  next();
});

io.engine.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Socekt.IO Middleware");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Will that middleware `io.engine.use` called when I request to express js endpoint? `app.use(controller)`?

Comment: @kennarddh I am not 100% sure, see my edit.

Comment: I have tried it and when I connect to `socket.io` only the `socket.io` middleware is called. Same with express middleware.